# how to do alignment for data that is returned as a reponse from perl script

Tags: html, perl, alignment

I am making a Jquery-Ajax call to perl script to fetch some data. Perl script will make a database query and return data to HTML page.

```
while (my @data = $statement->fetchrow_array())
{
    print "$data[6]  $data[3]  $data[5]";
    print "<br>";
}
```

Returned data is rendering in HTML page in glued form. I want to display the data in some alignment form.
Max length for `data[6]` can be `20`. and 10 10 for other two.

How can I do that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `<table>..</table>` looks like good candidate for data alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by mpapec:

```
print "<table>\n";
while (my @data = $statement->fetchrow_array()) {
    print "\t<tr>\n";
    print "\t\t<td>$_</td>\n" foreach ($data[6], $data[3], $data[5]);
    print "\t</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```